# how to play audio from WebView even when I exit the app?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm developing an Android App in Android Studio and in that a sound has to play on the WebView. But when I close the app, it automatically stops playing the audio. Now I want to know how do I make the audio to play in the background even if I close the app. (Kindly provide the code, I'm new to android development.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I think it's impossible.
To play a sound in background, you need to play the audio in Service.
It's only one way to play background sound.

I will show a code for that:

```
public class serv extends Service{

    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {   
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
        mp.setLooping(false);
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    {       
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startid){

        Log.d(tag, "On start");
        mp.start();
    }
}
```